# How to change y axis labels to 10^n

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the y axis on my plot to 10^n. I've read a couple of post that show was to change the y axis to scientific notation (`labels = scales::scientific`) but that's not what I am looking for. What I want my y axis to say is 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, and 10^5 however I can't seem to find out how to do this.

Here is an example of my data

```
bar <- structure(list(pos = 1:79, val = c(68129.20691, 14216.01188, 
6390.804842, 3710.602599, 2296.736176, 1515.498656, 1032.497215, 
774.2636827, 618.9658189, 395.5689752, 287.2984833, 208.6625183, 
183.6068538, 137.6857165, 113.6463666, 96.85256149, 72.62917502, 
65.98488201, 35.93813664, 34.80700588, 37.10602599, 17.22309159, 
19.57341781, 16.15598098, 11.00694171, 7.034321639, 5.994842503, 
7.034321639, 5.994842503, 2.020949938, 4.084238653, 2.020949938, 
5.108969775, 1, 1, 2.020949938, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2.020949938, 
0, 2.020949938, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-79L))
```

Here is the code that I am using to make the graph

```
ggplot(bar, aes(pos,val, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans=scales::pseudo_log_trans(base = 10),
    breaks=c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000),expand = c(0, 0),
  ) +

  scale_x_continuous(
    minor_breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20),
    breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20), limits = c(0, 100),
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)),
    guide = "axis_minor"
  ) +
  guides(x.sec = "axis_minor", y.sec = "axis_minor") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("grey", "red"), .3)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x.top = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y.right = element_blank()
  ) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "lr")
```

Comment: You can use `labels = scales::math_format(format = log10)` in the y scale.

Comment: @teunbrand that sort of works. I tried that as well but 10^0 ends up looking strange. It looks like `10^-4821637e-17`

Comment: https://r-graphics.org/recipe-axes-axis-log

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I believe that `scale_y_log10` messes up the bottom of the graph. The y-axis is now correct but not the x-axis is messed up. I tried using `scale_y_log10` before posting the question and that is what I believe messes up the bottom of the graph. I belive there is a post somewhere on here talking bout why this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the labels in your `scale_y_continuous` call manually using plotmath expressions.  For example, keep everything else the same, but use

```
scale_y_continuous(trans=scales::pseudo_log_trans(base = 10),
                   breaks=c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000), 
                   labels = expression(1, 10, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5),
                   expand = c(0, 0))
```

and you should get a plot like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Magical, that will do it. I just change the labels to this `labels = expression(10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5)`

Comment: I just looked at the help page, and it doesn't mention this as being legal.  But ggplot2 in general supports plotmath, so it was a lucky guess it would work here too.

Comment: Interesting, well hopefully your answer will help someone in the future with the same problem